# disable keep-alive in NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, sockets, nsurlconnection, keep-alive

How can I disable keep-alive when using NSURLConnection? Seems, that after cancelling and close it it still saves somewhere a socket that I was connected to server with and while the server fetches for information i cannot access another urls from the same server. I wonder if there is a way to completely reset a socket and start another one.

Thanks,

Nava

Comment: What do you mean by "while the server fetches for information" and "i cannot access another urls"?

Comment: My application gets xml files from the server. To get xml files I'm using different urls, all pointing to the same server. When the server can't get some xml from a certain url (I define a timeout in my NSURLConnection) I trow a timeout error, which notifies the user, that there is a problem with the server, so the GUI is not stuck, but if the user navigates through the application and tries to reach another url, the application doesn't get response from the server since it still stuck with the previous request.The question is how to close/reset the underlying socket?

Comment: "the application doesn't get response from the server since it still stuck with the previous request". Why is that, though? How are you *certain* that it's specifically a problem with the low-level socket not being closed? Could there be another reason?

Comment: I debugged my code and saw that after the problematic url on any url I try to reach NSURLConnection comes only to didFailWithError delegate of NSURLConnection with a timeout error, which made me think of the possibility that on low level the connection is not closed. That's also what I found from googling on NSURLConnection issues.

Comment: @ShaggyFrog/@NavaCarmon - is there anyway to disable keep-alive in NSURLConnection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting timeout on the server solved the problem

Comment: is there anyway to disable keep-alive in NSURLConnection ?